# How do I output all properties of an object?

Tags: javascript

```
var test={
  dha1:'Boolean',
  dha2:'Boolean',
  dha3:'Number',
  dha4:'String'
}

for(x in test){
  console.log(test.x);
}
```

Here i want my output as 
Boolean
Boolean
Number
String

But its return undefined for all four properties

Comment: "for all four properties"?? You're just retrieving one property only, and that doesn't exist. You need to use bracket notation here: `console.log(test[x])`.

Comment: Ok thanks.. but  why '.x' is not working here?

Comment: Because .x is trying to output a property called x (literally test.x) which does not exit, not read a property called the **value** of x

Comment: Because `test.x` is literally `test.x`, `x` here isn't the variable `x`, it's just a property name. Bracket notation allows you to use strings as property names, or variables containing a string.

Comment: Ah, there's the duplicate I was looking for....

Comment: Also see [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/218196)

Comment: console.log(typeof(x)) is correct ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `test[x]` instead of `test.x`.

```
var test={
  dha1:'Boolean',
  dha2:'Boolean',
  dha3:'Number',
  dha4:'String'
}

for(x in test){
  console.log(test[x]);
}
```

Comment: [Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/rr4smbdm/1/)